# Printing contents of matrix by using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

Here is my assignment:
**arrPrintMatrix(int *matrix, int m, int n): prints the content of the
matrix[m][n] to the screen in table format.**

And here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>

    int main() {

    void arrPrintMatrix(int *matrix, int m, int n);

    int matrix[2][3] = {{5, 10 , 15}, {0, 2, 4}};
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &matrix[0][0];
    arrPrintMatrix(ptr, 2, 3);

    return 0;
    }


    void arrPrintMatrix(int *matrix, int m, int n) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i] + j);
        }
    }

    }
```

But when I run this code, I get 5 6 and 7 as first row, 10 11 and 12 as second row. So something wrong with **matrix[i] + j**. How should I fix this?

By the way, I'm so confused about arrays of pointers, malloc, pointers to functions, so generally I'm confused about pointers. I would be glad if you suggest some web pages or videos about that.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info.

Comment: Change `void arrPrintMatrix(int *matrix, int m, int n)` as `void arrPrintMatrix(int **matrix, int m, int n) `

Comment: Thanks self. 
@Grijesh, when I do like that, it's returning 5, 9, 13 and 10, 14, 18.

Comment: @lombranzo Also change `printf("%d\t", matrix[i] + j);` to `printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);`

Comment: Thanks @Grijesh, but it didn't work again. What is the purpose of using double *? It's something special for 2D arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
        printf("%d\t", matrix[i] + j);
```

to

```
        printf("%d\t", matrix[i*n+j]);
```

**Update**

Layout of memory of 2D arrays is nicely explained in [this article](http://fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is the what I wanted. Like I wrote in first post, if you could suggest some pages or videos about using arrays of pointers, malloc etc...I would be glad.

Comment: @lombranzo I added a link to a URL about memory layout of 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1):

mChange:

```
 matrix[i] + j
```

To:

```
matrix[(i*n)+j]
```

Comment: "m" is row number in here. I think, it should be column number, so "n".
Thanks Mahonri.